# How I make “Reformat Code" not to split simple array into multiline?

Tags: phpstorm

I  PhpStorm 2023 when I make “Reformat Code” line with simple array

```php
protected $fillable
    = ['branch_id', 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name',  'department_id', 'status', 'job_start','job_end',
        'phones', 'website', 'notes', 'last_login', 'gender', 'birthday', 'salary', 'country', 'state_id',
        'region_id', 'subregion_id', 'city_id', 'street', 'postal_code' ];
```

is rendered into multiline code :

```php
protected $fillable
    = ['branch_id',
        'user_id',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'department_id',
        'status',
        'job_start',
        'job_end',
        'phones',
        'website',
        'notes',
        'last_login',
        'gender',
        'birthday',
        'salary',
        'country',
        'state_id',
        'region_id',
        'subregion_id',
        'city_id',
        'street',
        'postal_code'];
```

I dislike this way... How to make it not to split the code into multiple lines within 120 chars (margin in the editor)?

Comment: You might want to set "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | PHP > Array initializer" to "Do not wrap", that should help.

Comment: I did not find any “Do not wrap” under “Array initializer” : https://prnt.sc/ebUs9gw712Ia

Comment: @mstdmstd It is there. Just select that option instead of your current "Chop down if long"